# execute multiple TimerTask in for loop

Tags: java

i have my TimerTask that plays a music (shows its time in the console), and i wanna plays multiples music (List) music begin when the other music is over. when i use forloop its not working. any other solution ?

My TimerTask code :

```
public class MusicPlayer extends TimerTask {
    private int duree;
    private LocalTime time;
    public MusicPlayer(int duree) {
        this.duree = duree;
        time=LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(duree);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(time);
        time=time.minusSeconds(1);
        duree--;
        if (duree< 0)
            this.cancel();
    }
}
```

my function that runs the timertask:

```
public  void  readMusic(Music m) {
        System.out.println("====>Reading Music :");
        System.out.println("======>Name :"+m.getName());
        System.out.println("======>Nom de l'artiste :"+m.getNom_artiste());
        Timer timer=new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MusicPlayer(m.getDuree()), 0);
}
```

my forloop :

```
List<Music> musics = myPlayList.getMusicList();
            musics.forEach(music -> {
                musicService.readMusic(music);
            });
```

Comment: where is the for loop within the code? Can you post the exact code instead of extracting snippets - which would help clarify where the issue is?

Comment: he is the loop musics.forEach(music -> {
                musicService.readMusic(music);
            }); musics il a list

Comment: the issue is the execution don't give the behavior that i want : music runs after the other music is over